# how to concatenate string in python inside a test run method?

Tags: python

I have one method and its parameters are as below:

```
func_stat.update(utils.run_test_cases(api_tests.APITest(apiclient).AWS_post_provider()))
```

i want to make this "AWS_post_provider()" as a variable and execute as a whole.

Hence i read it from command line and concatenate. but it did not work.

```
 tname = sys.argv[4]
    testapp='api_tests.APITest(apiclient).'+tname
    func_stat.update(utils.run_test_cases(testapp))
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: There's not enough here for anyone to give you a definite answer. You need to expand on 'it did not work' and show the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your class or Module where the function is defined conatins a map called 
    `__dict__`

You can search for the function of interest in this dictionary. Key is name of the function and value the callable